# Calling a merged dictionary in Gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim

I have a file that I thought was a Gensim Dictionary file, but apparently it is not one.  I created it by merging dictionaries: `baseddict.merge_with(addddict)`.

However, now when I try to call doc2bow on it like this:

```
class MyCorpus(object):    
    def __init__(self,arrayxx,dictionaryx):
        self.arr = arrayxx
        self.diction = dictionaryx

    def __iter__(self):
        for each in self.arr:
            yield self.diction.doc2bow(each)
```

I get an error:

> File "/home/rnczf01/Desktop/Files/Patent_sim/newpython/parse_xml_patentsall_embedded_pftaps_allfiles.py",
>   line 58, in **iter**
>       yield self.diction.doc2bow(each) AttributeError: 'VocabTransform' object has no attribute 'doc2bow'